# C++ conversion between different types with the same layout

Tags: c++

If I have two structs that are defined identically, what is the best way to convert between them?

```
struct A { int i; float f; };
struct B { int i; float f; };
void Func1(A);
void Func2(B);
```

`Func2` needs to call `Func1` by taking the `B` parameter and make it an `A`. It would look like:

```
void Func2(B b) { Func1( (A) b); } //Obviously invalid cast
```

While creating an `A` and copying the members individually is a solution, this situation is going to occur with many different pairs of structs in many functions. Unfortunately, modifying the definitions of `A`, `B` or `Func1` is impossible, as well as the signature of `Func2`.

As far as I know, structs `A` and `B` will be represented identically in memory. What is the fastest way to convert between two such structs while not violating anything like strict aliasing?

Comment: If the structs are really this small, I would just copy the members and have no risk of undefined behavior.

Comment: I know. I just want to avoid it because there are about a hundred of these structs. Being able to reinterpert the structs would be much simpler for me than writing a ton of inline functions, but discovering that there is not a better way would be an equally helpful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can cast pointers. But there's no need. Since you're passing by value you need to create an instance of correct type anyway, so just do

```
void f2( B b ) { f1( A{ b.i, b.f } ); }
```

Simple.

Don't think about casts when straightforward type safe code will do what you need.

Comment: Good point - I didn't notice that the parameter is going to be copied anyway, so there's nothing to be gained by avoiding it.

Answer (score 0):

You can yse proxy class BA in definition of Func2():

```
#include <iostream>
struct A { int i; float f; };
struct B { int i; float f; };
struct BA
{
  const B &b_;
  BA(const B &b)
  : b_(b) {}
  operator A() const
  {
     A a = {b_.i, b_.f};
     return a;
  }
};
void Func1(A a) { std::cout << a.i << " " << a.f << std::endl;};
void Func2(B b) { Func1(BA(b)); }
int main()
{
   B b = {2, 42.};
   Func2(b);
   return 0;
}
```